# Need a proper English expression to reflect a concept

Tags: vocabulary

I am working on translating software and its documentation to English. This software basically organizes and stores technical documents.

A document may consist of a set of various files, stored on a server. Usually, only one user will work on a document, while others could download its files.

I would like to have a name for this set of files, relative to the document. I am thinking of *body of the document* but I am not sure that it sounds OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the word "library" for everything then the word "collection" for the categories within it.  A "volume" for an individual file. The workable file called the "master" while the others are "read-only" Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a little bit vague, but *body of the document* is definitely not appropriate as this would usually refer to the core content of the document itself.

The term *consist in* is ungrammatical and slightly confusing (*consist of* or *exist in* are grammatically correct but have opposite meanings in this context.)

- If you are trying to refer to a set of files that supports and contributes to a central document, you may be looking for a term like *supporting fileset*.
- If you are trying to refer to a set of files that contains this document along with a number of others, you may wish to refer to the document's *parent repository*.

I hope I've understood your question correctly!

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have corrected that *consist in* mistake (I should have known). I think that “supporting fileset” is a good approach, but I wonder whether it may be consistent with the fact that every frozen revision of a document will be archived in the system. Therefore there will be several filesets for a document, one of them will be the corpus of the last revision?

Comment: You're very welcome :-)